Replace null from another row
I have a scenario where I am struggling to write the logic. I tried case and max functions, but it's not working.
I have a table as shown below, with key columns Ref1 and Ref2. Now there is a scenario where I need to replace a value in one column with another column if the value in first column is null, but here the catch is this value is in a different row, and this need to be done only for the cases where TID in a group is 501 and 502 and TCD is 43. Within a group where we this TIDs 501 and 502 along with 43, there wont be any other id will be present
For example as shown the table for first two records, within a group (Ref1 and Ref2), I have TIDs with value 501 and 502 and TCD with values 43. Now in this case for both the rows TDATE have values. so in this case I can ignore the 2nd row and get only the first row as output.
Now if I take the ex. of row 6 and row 7, within a group (Ref1 and Ref2) I have TIDs with value 501 and 502 and TCD with values 43, but the TDATE for row 6 is NULL , so I need only row 7 as output and row 6 need to be ignored.
Now if I take the ex. of row 8 and row 9, within a group (Ref1 and Ref2) I have TIDs with value 501 and 502 and TCD with values 43, but the TDATE for row 9 is NULL , so anyway we need to take the row with TID 501 and other row can be ignored.
Rest all records should come as it is in the output.



Ref1
Ref2
TID
TCD
TDATE




800
900
501
43
2024-12-31


800
900
502
43
2024-12-22


345
934
544
35
2023-10-23


345
934
543
36
2023-11-21


700
876
501
43
NULL


700
876
502
43
2024-01-01


655
543
501
43
2024-04-25


655
543
502
43
NULL


434
465
411
37
2023-05-23


434
465
423
37
2024-06-12



Expected output is shown here:



Ref1
Ref2
TID
TCD
TDATE




800
900
501
43
2024-12-31


345
934
544
35
2023-10-23


345
934
543
36
2023-11-21


700
876
502
43
2024-01-01


655
543
501
43
2024-04-25


434
465
411
37
2023-05-23


434
465
423
37
2024-06-12




you can use CASE and ROW_NUMBER functions to achieve this. Here is the code:
WITH ranked_data AS (
  SELECT 
    Ref1, Ref2, TID, TCD, TDATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ref1, Ref2 ORDER BY TDATE) AS rn,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TDATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Ref1, Ref2) AS cnt
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT 
  Ref1, Ref2, TID, TCD, 
  CASE 
    WHEN TDATE IS NULL AND cnt > 0 THEN (SELECT MAX(TDATE) FROM ranked_data WHERE Ref1 = rd.Ref1 AND Ref2 = rd.Ref2)
    ELSE TDATE
  END AS TDATE
FROM ranked_data rd
WHERE rn = 1 OR TDATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Ref1, Ref2, TID;


The ROW_NUMBER function assigns a unique row number to each row
within each group of Ref1 and Ref2.
The COUNT window function counts the number of rows with non-NULL TDATE values within each group of Ref1 and Ref2.
The outer query selects only the rows with rn  = 1 or rows with non NULL TDATE values.
The CASE statement on the outer query replaces the TDATE value with the maximum TDATE value from the same group.


COUNT(CASE WHEN TDATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) can also be expressed as COUNT(TDATE).
